# Finding Index of last character in an input string JAVA?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, indexof

I'm trying to figure out how I can find the index of the last character in the first word in a String variable, while using Scanner class to get the String. In my code I need to use a single String for full name, and find the index of the last character in the first name.

So far I made this:

```java
String fullName;
        
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        
System.out.println("Insert full name: "); //For example: Joseph Adams.

fullName = s.nextLine();
    
int position = fullName.indexOf(" ");

System.out.println(fullName.substring(0, position)); 
//I need to find the index of h in Joseph.
```

Comment: Isn't it just `position - 1`?

Comment: `String str = fullName.split(" ")` then just do this 
 `int index = str[0]. length-1`

Answer (score 0):

The index of the last character in the string is just `str.length() - 1`. For example, to find the index of the `h` in `"Joseph"`:

```java
public static int indexOfLast(String str){
   return str.length() - 1;                
}
```

The length of `"Joseph"` is `6` but there is no character at index `6` (Strings, like arrays, start with the first element at index `0`). So, we subtract `1`to get `5`, which is the final character in the String. So doing:

```
String name = "Joseph";
name.charAt(indexOfLast(name));
```

will return `h`.

Comment: That’s a pointless function, as `str.length() - 1` is already the index of the character. Even worse, if the character occurs multiple times in the string, the redundant `str.indexOf(str.charAt(…))` will evaluate to the wrong index.

Comment: @Holger I originally thought that the question was asking for the first index of the final character, and that any instances of the character before the last would count.

Answer (score 0):

> Find the index of the last character of the first word

Try this.

- the first method subtracts one from the index of the first space which would be the letter `h`.
- the second method splits the string into two parts.  Part[0] is `joseph`. So the `h` is at the length of that string less 1.

```
String str = "Joseph Adams";
int index = str.indexOf(" ");
if(index < 0) {
   index = str.length();
}
System.out.println(index-1);

// or

String[] parts = str.split("\\s+");
int len = parts[0].length();
System.out.println(len-1);
```

Prints

```
5
5
```

Comment: i need to find the index of "h" in the input string. but your answer was the closest so far!

Comment: @gibby Index of 'H'???? or index of last character before space????
in above code "int index" is the index of space. (index -1) is the index of char before space.

Comment: Unfortunately, telling me it's close doesn't tell me what is wrong with it.  Please elaborate.